# Laravel page speed analysis

Tags: jquery, laravel

I got a page on my laravel app which is very slow to load. It typically display a list of email that the app sent.

It seems a getByType something is slowing down the process.

Initially I thought this is a jquery as it show initiator to be a jquery.

But then when I search in my app I find this:

[image]

```
Route::post('/getByType', array('as' => 'mail.type.get', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\Mail\MailController@getByType'));




// get emails by type
    public function getByType(){
        $type = Input::get('type');
        if(!$type)
            $mails = Email::all()->toArray();
        else
            $mails = Email::where('type','=',$type)->get()->toArray();
        
        $mail_url = route("ajax.supplier.mailbody");
        return View::make('backend/base/contact/mail_parts/table',compact('mails','mail_url'));
    }
```

According to you what make it so slow to load this element ? The Ajax call ?

This is how is the "backend/base/contact/mail_parts/table"

```
<div class="" id="mail_div">
<table class="listTable display table dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Sent By</th>
            <th>Sent To</th>
            <th>CC</th>
            <th>BCC</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Resend</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>I.P.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
        @foreach($mails as $mail)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $mail['subject'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mail['type'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mail['sent_by'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mail['sent_to'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ displaySerialized( $mail['cc'] ) }}</td>
            <td>{{ displaySerialized( $mail['bcc'] ) }}</td>
            <td id="{{ $mail['id'] }}" class="mail_body"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button">click to open</button></td>
            <td ><a href="{{URL::route('admin.email.resend',$mail['id'])}}"><button class="btn btn-aqc-red btn-aqc-xs" type="button">Resend</button></a></td>
            <td>{{ $mail['created_at'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mail['ip'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's likely slow because you have many, many `Email` records and you're fetching every single one of them. Do you really need to do that? Surely you can paginate it?

Comment: @ceejayoz actually i see they are already paginated so i don't think this is the problem...

Comment: If you don't have an index defined on the `type` column on database, defining an index would also help improve performance at database level

Comment: They might be paginated in the view, but that's just presentation. You're getting all the emails from the database. In this context, pagination would mean you only retrieve the mails shown on the first page. And then get the mails on the second page when you need them

Comment: @IGP good remark about the pagination only on the view. I am going to check this.

Comment: I'd recommend using `cursor()` instead of `get()` as well since you don't seem to care for the Collection object. More details on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following lines:

```php
if(!$type)
    $mails = Email::all()->toArray();
else
    $mails = Email::where('type','=',$type)->get()->toArray();
```

to:

```php
if(!$type)
    $mails = Email::cursor()->toArray();
else
    $mails = Email::where('type','=',$type)->cursor()->toArray();
```

This should lower your memory usage quite a bit, which in turn might speed up your application. It's still bad to retrieve all the emails at once because that won't scale well but this way, at least you avoid creating a full Eloquent Collection.

**No changes to the view need to be made for this approach to work.**

Depending on how the `'backend/base/contact/mail_parts/table'` view uses the `$mails` variable, there might be a way to make another optimization.

#### EDIT:

Given how you use the `$mails` variable, can you try the following?

```
public function getByType()
{
    $type = Input::get('type');

    // Return LazyCollection of emails instead of array
    if(!$type)
        $mails = Email::cursor();
    else
        $mails = Email::where('type', '=', $type)->cursor();
        
    $mail_url = route("ajax.supplier.mailbody");

    return View::make('backend/base/contact/mail_parts/table', compact('mails', 'mail_url'));
}
```

```xml
<!-- Since you're not iterating over an array anymore, some changes need to be made -->
@foreach($mails as $mail)
    <tr>
        <!-- Since ->toArray() wasn't used, each $mail is an object -->
        <td>{{ $mail->subject }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mail->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mail->sent_by }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mail->sent_to }}</td>
        <td>{{ displaySerialized( $mail->cc ) }}</td>
        <td>{{ displaySerialized( $mail->bcc ) }}</td>
        <td id="{{ $mail->id }}" class="mail_body">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" type="button">click to open</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ URL::route('admin.email.resend', $mail->id) }}">
                <button class="btn btn-aqc-red btn-aqc-xs" type="button">Resend</button>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $mail->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $mail->ip }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I added in the initial post how view use the mails variable

Comment: @user92481 why you're not using pagination?

Comment: @sta  am not the one who developped this code. I took it over from another dev...